# Heyawake - help continue puzzle (2)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Hint needed. The cells marked with dots must be white.[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for this puzzle? Also, the rules may be found here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyawake) for this type of puzzle. Also also, why did you mark some squares with dots?

Comment: I can confirm that op is correct so far. One option  is to deduce based on there being a unique solution that the 2nd row 4th from the left is colored in. If it were not then the top middle one of that room could go either way...

Comment: This puzzle is from the book  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1783351365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a series of deductions marked as red, yellow, green, blue, and purple

> [image: puzzle solution]

The logic here is as follows:

> Red: you can't have an uncolored orthogonal line for more than 2 rooms, so this must be colored.

...

> Yellow: forced because of the 3 in that room and the red. (OP already figured out that the three is necessary because of the empty rooms on either side.)

...

> Green: needed because otherwise there would be three rooms.

...

> Blue: 3 rooms

...

> Purple: 3 rooms.